# Get All Field Values on Row

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using the code below to get all values from a row.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from python_lib.models import Field

field = Field.all()[0]
names = Field.properties()

for key in names:
  print field.get(key)
```

But it giving the following error,

```
BadKeyError: Invalid string key name.
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out ``names`` and ``field.keys()`` - because perhaps the error is valid.

Comment: @sotapme The names are printing correctly. The problem arise when I use them to print values from field using Get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing too different api's in this code.

```
for key in names:
   print field.get(key)
```

Your get() call is invalid, as your are actually trying to call a class method to fetch an entity from the datastore  - see the docs for this method  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get .

To get a property by name from an instance of field (your object)  you should be using `getattr`

as in

```
for key in names:
    print getattr(field,key)
```

or all alternately use `get_value_for_datastore(model_instance)` of the property object, which is returned from properties()  call along with the name of the property.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Field(db.Model):
  author = db.StringProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

a = Field(author="me")
a.put()
```

EDIT:

```
field = Field.all()
for f in field:
    print f.author
    print f.content


props = Field.properties()

print props
for vals in props:
  print vals
```

output:

```
<__main__.Field object at 0xb8c9e4c>
{'content': <google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty object at 0xb7c0aec>, 'date':     <google.appengine.ext.db.DateTimeProperty object at 0xb7c06cc>, 'author':     <google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty object at 0xb7c0f6c>}
content
date
author
```

Comment: This will print only names. I want to get values from field object.

Comment: The properties are field names etc The values are from the query - Also have a look at ndb https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/